# How to load newest website through android webview

Tags: android, webview

I have created an app that allows my website to be viewed in an android app however it does not load the newest version of the website how would I do this?

Thanks
Tim

Comment: Does your app scrape the web and convert into an app? Are you populating `TextView`s from scraped content? Please explain or paste some code. You question is fairly generic.

Comment: If my answer helped you out, please feel free to accept it :)

Answer (score 3):

You should probably clear Cache via

```
myBrowser.clearCache(true)
```

just after creating it, before loading any pages.